# Countplot with relative frequencies or density curves

Tags: python, comparison, seaborn, distribution, categorical-data

I am trying to visualize categorical data for three groups (hues) of data. Using seaborn, it seems like countplot() may do the trick (the second example in the documentation link below looks like what I need). But instead of counts on the y-axis, is it possible to make this the proportion by group?

In the second example in the link, the Man group (blue bar) would be roughly 22%, 18%, 60% in first, second, and third class, respectively, rather than the counts. The same would be done for the Woman and Child groups.

[Seaborn Example](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.countplot.html#seaborn.countplot)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, this isn't an option directly in Seaborn, but you can manually create a proportional counts data set and plot with `sns.barplot`:

```py
df = sns.load_dataset('titanic')
# [1] Simple count
sns.countplot(x='class', data=df)
plt.show()
# [1B] By percent
pct = df['class'].value_counts(normalize=True).reset_index().rename({'index':'class','class':'percent'}, axis=1)
sns.barplot(x='class', y='percent', data=pct)
plt.show()

# [2] Two var count
sns.countplot(x='class', hue='who', data=df)
plt.show()
# [2b] By percent
pct2 = (df.groupby(['class','who']).size() / df.groupby(['class']).size()).reset_index().rename({0:'percent'}, axis=1)
sns.barplot(x='class', hue='who', y='percent', data=pct2)
plt.show()
```

[image]

[image]

---

#### Edits per comment

You can revise what percentage you're calculating fairly easily by changing the denominator of the fraction used to calculate the `pct` dataframe.

```py
# [3] Grouped by 'class'; hue by 'who'
# IIUC, this is what you're asking for
pct3 = (df.groupby(['class','who']).size() / df.groupby(['who']).size()).reset_index().rename({0:'percent'}, axis=1)
sns.barplot(x='class', hue='who', y='percent', data=pct3)
plt.show()
```

[image]

You can also change the groupings by swapping the `hue` and `x` arguments in the `sns.boxplot` command. In my view, this second option is a bit more intuitive.

```py
# [3b] Grouped by 'who'; hue by 'class'
# In my view, this is a bit more intuitive; each grouping sums to 100%, 
# and you can compare across class for men, women, and children more easily
sns.barplot(x='who', hue='class', y='percent', data=pct3)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Brendan, good to know it’s possible with a little tweaking. How would you show the second chart with each “who” group equaling 1 across all three “classes”? It looks like the three bars in each class total 1, but I’m interested in each hue totaling 1. Does that make sense?